# Multiple infovis bar charts do not work

Tags: infovis, thejit

How can I have 2 bar charts plotted in 2 different divs on a single web page? If I try to do so one bar chart gets overwritten with the values of the second chart since the library looks for hardcoded div name 'infovis'. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: You can look for some other charting library. For example, http://manicharts.com They have given documentation and chart can be used as plugin without any dependance on div or ID.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but I'd like to share what I've done.

First create two div's:

```
<div id='InfoVisChart1'></div>
<div id='InfoVisChart2'></div>
```

Then, in your JS, where you write in your code, inject into the two id's:

```
var barChart = new $jit.BarChart({  
//id of the visualization container  
  injectInto: 'InfoVisChart1',
.... etc.

var barChart2 = new $jit.BarChart({  
//id of the visualization container  
  injectInto: 'InfoVisChart2',
.... etc.
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

BarCharts inherit of the Canvas object, so we can make use of canvas options described [here](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Options/Options-Canvas-js.html#Options.Canvas).

What you need is "injectInto": this option allows to set the ID of your container DIVs.